# Views not appearing in viewpager

Tags: android

I'm trying to build a viewpager for the first time. I'm populating an ArrayList of views in the main onCreate method and passing it to the constructor of the PagerAdapter. The activity launches fine and I can see the ViewPager (or at least its background) but none of the views appear in it, I just see the blank background. I've tried inflating layout XMLs that I know are working in other widgets, so it can't be a problem there. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I have the instantiateObject method written. Anyway, here is my adapter:

```
    public class StoryAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private ViewBuilder viewBuilder;

    public StoryAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<View> views){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {         
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View arg0, int arg1) {
            View v = views.get(arg1);
            ((ViewPager) arg0).addView(v);
            return v;
            }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View pager, int arg1, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);

}
}
```

and here is my onCreate():

```
public class ShowStory extends Activity {
public int totalPages;
Button backBtn;
public String text;
public ArrayList<View> views;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_story);

    backBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);        
            finish();       
        }
    });
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.storyFlipper);
    views = new ArrayList<View>();

    View v0 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.galleryview, null);

    TextView v0t = (TextView)v0.findViewById(R.id.headline);
    v0t.setText("COVER1");

    View v1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.coverpage, null);
//      TextView v1t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coverText);
//      v1t.setText("COVER2");      

    View v2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.coverpage, null);
//      TextView v2t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coverText);
//      v2t.setText("COVER3");  

views.add(v0);
views.add(v1);
views.add(v2);  


    StoryAdapter sa = new StoryAdapter(this, views);        
    vp.setAdapter(sa);
```

PS I'm doing this mainly for educational purposes, this is obviously a very simple example. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

------Edit: I tried what you suggested:

```
        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        resId = R.layout.coverpage;
        break;
    case 1:
        resId = R.layout.coverpage;
        break;
    case 2:
        resId = R.layout.coverpage;
        break;
    case 3:
        resId = R.layout.coverpage;
        break;

    }
    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;

    }
```

and have the same result - I see the blank background of the viewpager, but no views appear

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I figured it out - it was because I didn't have anything in the isViewFromObject method. Replacing null with

```
return arg0 == (View) arg1;
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Why didn't they make isViewFromObject() abstract!? Anyway, thanks! You've helped me.

Comment: Thanks. Great help

Answer (score 0):

I think that the views need to be inflated inside the instantiateItems method. This is how I did it:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

int resId = 0;
switch (position) {

case 0:
    resId = R.layout.first_layout_id;

    break;
case 1:
    resId = R.layout.layout_id;
    break;
case 2:
    resId = R.layout.layout_id;
    break;
case 3:
    resId = R.layout.layout_id;
    break;

}

View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);
((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
return view;

}
```